# How to run single task form multiple tasks?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have 10 tasks in my project but I want to run only one task from them when I fire a command like `gradle <task_name>` e.g Suppose I have 4 tasks A to D and if I run `gradle B` then it should run only that task but it runs all the tasks present in my grade script. I want to create a Jenkins job for the same. and in Jenkins job same problem occurs.

can anyone please help me out?